# lightdm fails to start

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg, lightdm, tty

I bought a Dell Vostro 3583 with pre-installed Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome3. I wanted to use lightdm and Xfce so I ran:

```
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies and some other packages
```

After configuring xfce4 and creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

I do have Radeon discrete card.

To prevent screen tearing effect I removed GNOME with:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell* gnome-desktop* gdm*
sudo apt autoremove
```

And then:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

I also installed lightdm-gtk-greeter but it didn't work.

and selected lightdm in next TUI (Text User Interface) dialog and then rebooted and I was greeted with tty1.

Here is output of `systemctl status lightdm` and `sudo lightdm --test-mod --debug` :

[image]

Also, I can't access tty7. I think I read somewhere that lightdm starts on tty7 and it does on my Arch Linux PC, but it https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-disable-all-tty-consoles-and-enable-only-1/ says that there are only 6 TTYs by default which makes me really confused.

Comment: Maybe better to just fresh install Xubuntu.. As far as tearing, by default Ubuntu and Intel wouldn't have any. As far as xfce4, not too sure that .conf would do anything as the TearFree option is only thru sna, by default 18.04 uses modesetting..

Answer (score 1):

I removed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and it started working again.